# 2 x % formulas in single cell

Tags: excel, formula, percentage

I am trying to get a `%` ratio in the `1` cell of `2 different numbers.

[image]

the % is based on the total amount of Fulltimer vs Labour Hire employees (each set is week 1/2/3/4)

I need the cell to show `"fulltimer% / casual%".`

I found the `GCD` function that worked for week 1.

```
=IFERROR(I134/(GCD(I130,I134))&"%-"&I130/(GCD(I130,I134))&"%","")
```

[image]

But when it got to week 4 it hasn't worked.

[image]

[image]

Doing a basic `%` formula works for a single `%`, but when I try to add them it shows as a text-formatted cell and I get it to change back to a `%` formatted cell.

[image]

Comment: `&` is a text join operator. If you need to use the operator to create a text string and want it interpreted as a number you can coerce it back by multiplying or dividing by 1 (will retain the number "format" (such as `%`)). eg. `"10%"/1=10%` or wrap it in the Value function which will follow the format of the cell. eg. `VALUE("10%") =0.1`